# What is the correct use of php-mysqlidb tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to find some questions on Stack Overflow about [PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class). I assumed that the tag [php-mysqlidb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-mysqlidb) would lead me there, however when I started browsing the questions newest first I could not find anything other than poorly written/tagged questions where people use the standard MySQLi library. I started to re-tag and VTC the questions, which I consider a task of little worth.

Is there something wrong with this tag or am I completely wrong that it is about MysqliDb?

## Update

I have gone through all of the question from these tag. I found few legit ones. The rest I re-tagged whatever I could. Some of them are unsalvageable IMO for example:

[Mariadb error Error Number: 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320413/mariadb-error-error-number-1064)
[http error 500 phpmyadmin Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483059/http-error-500-phpmyadmin-debian)
[PHP/MYSQL Why is this not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867030/php-mysql-why-is-this-not-working)

I voted to close them, but beyond that I don't know what to do. Even if they are closed they will still clutter this tag.

Comment: The tag wiki seems to indicate it's for the project you're mentioning.  Is the problem that questions are mistagged?

Comment: I have yet to find one which talks about that project, hence my confusion. I do not want to re-tag if I am in the wrong.

Comment: It is a bit like the three most important things for a fast-food restaurant: location, location, location.  For a library it is name, name, name.  There is no obvious solution until they/you can come up with a better name.  Until then, there's no better way to support this library at SO than retagging any off-questions.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with the tag itself, but some of our users are not using it correctly.

That library is not particularly well known or popular, so it’s likely you won’t find many questions about it.

Apparently, some users have mistagged their questions about [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli) with this tag. This kind of thing happens all the time with many tags.

Try your search using Google, keywords and the `site:` operator. But considering the name of that wrapper, it wouldn’t surprise me you got many false positives.

The name of the project isn’t really helping. It’s just too generic. There are bound to be confusions, either by mistagging or simply because the keywords are all too similar.